# What should be the runtime of checking if two strings are anagrams

Tags: java, runtime, permutation, anagram

I wrote this function, and I THINK that the runtime would be O(nlogN), but I'm not exactly sure. Also, is there a CLEANER way to write this(java)? I feel like a more experienced programmer could do this with way less lines of code.

```
public static boolean anagramCheck(String strA, String strB){
  if(strA.length() != strB.length()){
  return false;
}

char arrA[] = strA.toCharArray();
char arrB[] = strB.toCharArray();

Arrays.sort(arrA);
Arrays.sort(arrB);

int j = 0;
for(char s : arrA){
    if(s != arrB[j]){
        return false;
    }
     j++;
  }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: O(n) - use hash table to count frequency and compare with second one.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, that is hardly O(n). You risk collisions in your hash table. If you have any, they will downgrade performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting is relatively expensive - O(n log n) - and in general is to be avoided if possible.

You can reduce the time complexity to O(n) by making one pass on each String to collect character frequencies, which can then be compared using `Map#equals`.

This can be done using only one line:

```
return strA.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()))
  .equals(strB.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting())));
```

[Try it online](https://ideone.com/xF7o3N).

---

Doubters that this code does in fact has a time complexity of O(n) can see [live timing test](https://ideone.com/RyJrLS) showing constant time per letter - ie O(n) (where n is the word length in letters).

Comment: It doesn’t compile. With that error corrected, I believe that my comment to  Alexei Levenkov is valid here too: with a map it’s hardly O(n).

Comment: @ole thanks for pointing out the compile problem. it needed `.boxed()` (one of the hazards of thumbing code on an iPhone - fixed now and live demo link added). And yes, this is O(n) because all operations on a HashMap are O(1). The comparison is something less than O(n) (due to dups) so it doesn't factor in.

Comment: I’m still curious about the O(n) claim. `HashMap` guarantees constant time operations only if “hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets“. This might (or might not) hold true for characters in general, but who knows for the characters in the anagram candidate?

Comment: @Ole `String#chars()` returns the characters as an `IntStream`, which (after boxing into `Integer`) have hashcodes of themselves, so there will be no hash collisions, HashMap's internal hashing algorithm will use these int hashcodes to distribute the chars evenly enough across the buckets.

Comment: Possibly. I’m not convinced.

Comment: @Ole be convinced - see [live timing test for word lengths 10-100K](https://ideone.com/RyJrLS) showing O(n)

Comment: There are 2^16 possible char values, so with a default load factor and initial capacity (0.75f and 16) there is a maximum capacity we may reach. For each possible capacity there is a max bucket/bin size (it might be 1 or 500, but it’s finite). So there is a max time for `put()` and `get()` so we may consider them constant. For char valued keys I’m convinced. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity of your algorithm is O(nlogn).